# cannot convert system.data.datagridview to object[]

Tags: c#, wcf, dataview

i am trying to save update ,delete, and insert on datagridview using services of a wcf

```
private void SaveAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReferenceExemplaires.ServiceExemplairesClient se=new ServiceReferenceExemplaires.ServiceExemplairesClient();
    DataView oView = (DataView)gridData.DataSource;
    se.saveAll(oView);
}
```

the error is coming from se.saveAll(oView) at the parameter
i think the problem is with wcf ,because without exposing the services it's fine

```
ServiceExemplaires se = new ServiceExemplaires();
DataView oView = (DataView)gridData.DataSource;
se.saveAll(oView);
```

but the idea was to use wcf to access the service from another machine

Comment: We don't know the type of the parameters for `saveAll` which makes it hard to answer your question. If it really takes an `object[]` that makes it even more confusing because all that tells you is you have to pass an array of something.... What that something is, is entirely unknown.

Comment: the type of the parameter is supposed to be a  dataview

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? Does the saveAll function not accept the DataView?

If that is the case, try putting it like:

```
se.saveAll(new object[] {oView} );
```

Comment: i've got an error on parameter saying cannot convert system.data.datagridview to object[]

Comment: with your solution i've got another error  suggesting  to use datacontractresolver

Answer (score 0):

it seems dataviews are not seriazable ,
instead of trying to save any update ,delete or create within a datagridView and give all the dataview as a parameter to the wcf
i just used another form which tooks all the paramaters with simple textBox and eventually pass one by one the value as a parameters to the wcf service